# Plain Javascript as Angular 2 service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I need to add a hosted third-party JavaScript file in an Angular 2 component.  This file is updated anytime a change is made in the associated third-party vendors proprietary system, so I cannot simply pull down a copy, include it locally, and import it into the project.

Typically I would include this file at a top level in a script tag, and then simply use `declare <windowvar>: any` to get access to it.  However in this case, since the component itself is trying to load the script, I cannot declare the window variable because it does not exist on the window object at the time the component is loaded, which generates an error.

I can load the script by manually adding a script tag, and that works, however I need access to the window variable it creates in order to use it properly.  And I cannot simply use an interval to look for it because typescript throws a fit that `<windowvariable> does not exist on object window`.

Is there any way I can 1) Load the hosted JavaScript file inside the component, and 2) Get access to the window variable created by the loaded JavaScript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 1:** Based on the comments, the previous solution will be not help you.

You can do that by using **[OpaqueToken](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OpaqueToken-class.html)** in Angular2

**1**. Create a Token that is used to find an instance as below in a separate ts file.

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core'

export let name_of_The_Token = new OpaqueToken('name_Of_The_Window_Object');
```

**2.** In your **App.module**, you need to **import and declare a variable** that is the name of your window object which makes the Token as a angular2 service so that you can use properties, methods in that javascript file across your components.

```
import { name_of_The_Token } from '/* file_Path */';
declare let name_Of_The_Window_Object : any;  //below your import statements
```

Step 3: **Inject** it to providers array of your module.

```
{ provide : name_of_The_Token , useValue : name_Of_The_Window_Object }
```

Guidance to use this token in components

1. Import the token just like any other service and @Inject from angular-core

   ```
    import { name_of_The_Token } from '/* file_Path */';
    import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
   ```
2. In constructor of the component

   ```
    constructor(@Inject( name_of_The_Token ) private _serviceObject : any )
   ```
3. Any where in your component you can use the variables and methods of your javascript file as

   ```
    this._serviceObject.method1()
    this._serviceObject.variable1
    .....
   ```

**Note**: One drawback is that you will **not get intellisense**.

Overcoming it:
If you are looking for intellisense you need to **wrap the methods and variables inside an interface** and use it in the type**(instead of any)** of your token as

```
export interface myCustom {
      method1(args): return_Type;
      method2(args): void;
      .....
   }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/D6LY55XHPuaJHGZgIhoG?p=preview)** of ToasterService

Comment: This is not a package dependency in any way, it is a third party resource that must be loaded from their servers at the URL they provide.

Comment: is it just a javascript or a module with few features??

Comment: It is just a javascript file that creates a window object that I then need to be able to reference without typescript throwing a fit.

Comment: are you using that javascript methods in your angular2 components??

Comment: yes, which is why I need a reference to the window variable.

Comment: You cannot do that in typescript

Comment: Can you give more details as to why in an answer please?

Comment: was this you were expecting? @StephenRios

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly. Thank you, it's an elegant solution.

Comment: I will modify the title and tags to reach large ppl

Comment: All you need is `declare global { interface Window { whateverIsAddedToWindow: TypeOfWhateverIsAddedToWindow } }` nothing remotely this complex

Comment: @AluanHaddad down voted?  how you will get intellisense?

Comment: The only purpose of the `declare global` block is to provide intellisense, you can give that property any type that you wish.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you were in a module use `declare global` to augment the global scope. Otherwise, you're in a global script file in which case you don't need to wrap the augmentation. In both cases the `interface Window` declaration that you write will merge with all others including the one in `lib.d.ts`.

Comment: You mean like this https://plnkr.co/edit/cJxoSPVoHE56cFXmmxvO?p=preview ? If you wish to provide a facade for the global `toastr` object created by the script so that you may replace it during testing, then wrapping it in a service has merit but simply injecting the global as if it were a service is not useful since it still depends on the global. My understanding was the OP simply wanted to avoid the error from TypeScript because `toastr` was not  declared.

Comment: Actually, here is an even simpler version https://plnkr.co/edit/HZYKYDsi0a7Aq8PuSVHk?p=preview in which case we don't even need the global augmentation at all since the template uses the member directly, but it is nice to have it should we want to use it in the component's logic.

Comment: this is not a injectable service ?

Comment: Sure you could do that, but the text of the question does not really suggest that this is needed. The title of this question "Plain Javascript as Angular 2 service" does not make any sense. But sure, you can wrap it with `{ provide: 'toastr', useFactory: () => window.toastr }` and then `@Inject('toastr') toastr`, but what is the point?

Comment: are you in the intension to argue? if you feel you have a better solution answer it instead of downvoting others answers

Comment: You wrote "You cannot do that in typescript" in response to the comment "yes, which is why I need a reference to the window variable" which suggests you somehow think TypeScript has special rules as compared to JavaScript. I do intend to argue with that statement because it is patently false.

Comment: Sure thing, just be sure to learn TypeScript (and by implication JavaScript). Following Angular 2 tutorials does not qualify as learning the language. Consider reading _JavaScript: The Good Parts_ https://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742

Comment: also, it doesn't mean if your solution is good you can downvote some one else answers.

Comment: I downvoted because you suggested a solution to a non-existent problem. I added the plunkr, based on yours, to demonstrate nothing here (OpaqueToken nonsense) was required, when you asked me to do so. Seriously though lots of people seem to think TypeScript has different runtime behavior than JavaScript and that is untrue. Many people starting off with Angular 2 have no idea what TypeScript is and the Angular 2 tutorials mislead them. 99% of Angular 2 questions should have the JavaScript tag

Answer (score 0):

Effectively, you're trying to pick up a "global module" javascript library from a CDN. (I assume the 3rd-party lib is not in CommonJS, AMD, UMD, or other module format, since it is accessed through a sole global variable.)

So the first question is where is the corresponding .d.ts file?  It contains the names and interfaces that inform Typescript of the 'shape' of the library, as well as declaring that global variable will exist.  If your 3rd-party doesn't provide it you'll need to write it yourself.  It will contain not just the declaration of the global var, like

`declare var theGlobalVarInQuestion: IInterfaceOfStuffInsideLibrary;`

but also the declaration of said Interface, and its properties and their types, all the way down. Like this: https://github.com/catamphetamine/libphonenumber-js/blob/master/index.d.ts

You can include the .d.ts file in /node_modules/@types/nameOfSaidLibrary but you'd need to check it into your source repo (with possible .gitignore gymnastics) especially because a `npm prune` will remove it.  Or if you put it elsewhere, modify the tsconfig.json `typeroots` property to look in both that place in addition to its usual /node_modules/@types/ folder.

Just to be clear, the .d.ts file doesn't (and shouldn't) actually create the variable; it just states that it will be there so the Typescript compiler won't complain.  Whether or not it is there at runtime is decided by however you're loading the js.

If you're not loading it via script tag in the index.html, then either a Typescript `import` statement in the consuming component can do so (given the right config of SystemJS or whatever you're using) or the consuming component can dynamically create and append a new script tag to the index.html.  Just make sure your module loader isn't trying to download and immediately bundle it with the rest of your app at buildtime. It sounds like you want the lib to be downloaded anew each time at runtime.