# Using jquery plugin inside Angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to use this jQuery plugin https://github.com/kevinchappell/formBuilder in my ng-2 app. I know that is not considered as a good practice but I haven't found analogs writted in ng2 natively(I need drag-and-drop html form builder). 
So what approach should I choose? Wrap jquery plugin with ng2 component like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import "../../../node_modules/formBuilder/dist/form-builder.min.js"

@Component({
  selector: 'form-builder',
  template: '<div class="build-wrap></div>"'
  styleUrls: ['./form-builder.component.css']
})
export class FormBuilderComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  formBuilderElement: any;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.formBuilderElement = jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.build-wrap');
    this.formBuilderElement.formBuilder();
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, this code isn't working. It produces this error:

```
Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:17:6 caused by: this.formBuilderElement.formBuilder is not a function
```

This project was generated with angular-2-cli so I have included all necessary files into my angular-cli.json like this:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/formBuilder/dist/form-builder.min.css",
    "../node_modules/formBuilder/dist/form-render.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/formBuilder/dist/form-builder.min.js",
    "../node_modules/formBuilder/dist/form-render.min.js"
  ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235540/plain-javascript-as-angular-2-service/42235817#42235817

Comment: if you don't want to use jquery in angular then loading it by the document won't affect running angular app.