# how to add plugin javascript to angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, plugins

I have a template in HTML and CSS and Javascript. I split HTML and CSS to components but I cannot adopt javascript to angular.

how to add plugin javascript to angular 2

Comment: have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235540/plain-javascript-as-angular-2-service/42235817#42235817

Answer (score 0):

You can call the javascript functions from the component typescript file see:
[Angular 2 typescript invoke javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37348166/angular-2-typescript-invoke-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

You  may import the javascript library within your main index.html file and call it from an angular2 component. However that doesn't mean automatically it will work, as e.g. DOM-manipulation is done differently in Angular2, e.g via the [templates](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html).