# Using external javascript libraries in angular 2 lazy loaded module, not index.html

Tags: angular, angular-cli, external-js

So I want to include an external JS library, a carousel slider in the is case, to my Angular 2 app.  I have seen a lot of tutorials that show how it can be added I have done that successfully, but referencing the library on index.html.

This as you will know, will load the library every time the app is visited, regardless of whether they visit the components needing the carousel. Since it's pretty hefty, I only want to load it where it is needed, which is inside a lazy loaded module.

I haven't tried, but I'm sure I could just chuck the script tag in the component that uses it, but this doesn't feel right to me.

There must be a *right* way.  What is it!?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plain Javascript as Angular 2 service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235540/plain-javascript-as-angular-2-service)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We are doing this in one of our projects to load js libraries dynamically

**ScriptStore.ts** that will contain the **path** of the script either locally or on a remote server and a **name** that will be used to load the script dynamically

```
 interface Scripts {
    name: string;
    src: string;
}  
export const ScriptStore: Scripts[] = [
    {name: 'filepicker', src: 'https://api.filestackapi.com/filestack.js'},
    { name: 'rangeSlider', src: '../../../assets/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js' }
];
```

**script.service.ts** is an injectable service that will handle the loading of script, copy `script.service.ts` as it is

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {ScriptStore} from "./script.store";

declare var document: any;

@Injectable()
export class Script {

private scripts: any = {};

constructor() {
    ScriptStore.forEach((script: any) => {
        this.scripts[script.name] = {
            loaded: false,
            src: script.src
        };
    });
}

load(...scripts: string[]) {
    var promises: any[] = [];
    scripts.forEach((script) => promises.push(this.loadScript(script)));
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

loadScript(name: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //resolve if already loaded
        if (this.scripts[name].loaded) {
            resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Already Loaded'});
        }
        else {
            //load script
            let script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = this.scripts[name].src;
            if (script.readyState) {  //IE
                script.onreadystatechange = () => {
                    if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
                        script.onreadystatechange = null;
                        this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                        resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded'});
                    }
                };
            } else {  //Others
                script.onload = () => {
                    this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                    resolve({script: name, loaded: true, status: 'Loaded'});
                };
            }
            script.onerror = (error: any) => resolve({script: name, loaded: false, status: 'Loaded'});
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Inject this `ScriptService` wherever you need it and load js libs like this

```
this.script.load('filepicker', 'rangeSlider').then(data => {
            console.log('script loaded ', data);
        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on the type of the library you are trying to load and what is the module loader you are using on your application.

I'm going to assume you are using Typescript or at least ES6 syntax.

#### If your 3rd party dependency is a AMD/UMD/CommonJS module

In this case, on top of you component file you can just import it.

```
import {SomeClassName} from "path/to/library";
```

#### If your 3rd party is a global module (ex: JQuery plugin)

In this case you just need to import the js file and it will be available on a global variable.

```
import "path/to/library";
```

### Conclusion

In any case, you should check if the 3rd party library has already typings available, that will help you if you are using Typescript.

Depending on your module loader, you may need to make some configurations prior to this. But without more information is hard to help you.

Best,
jpsfs

Comment: If we use that last import statement in a component, could it be only available to that component? Like I have to use jquery, chart.js, and mymade.js files in order, could I use it like this: `import "path/to/jquery"; import "path/to/chart.js"; import "path/to/mymade.js"`???

Comment: @AnkurShah no. Using the last import statement it will load the file globally.