# Third part libs and Angular Universal [Angular 2]

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal, prism.js, universal-cli

I am using `prism.js` in my project and when I switch to `universal-cli` I get error in terminal from server side

> ReferenceError: Prism is not defined

in angular-cli.json I have prism script:

```
"scripts": [
    "assets/prism.js"
]
```

And from component I call it like this:

```
declare var Prism: any;
Prism.highlightAll();
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235540/plain-javascript-as-angular-2-service/42235817#42235817)

Comment: But how to add `Prism` to `OpaqueToken`?

Comment: add to script references in index.html or systemjs or anywhere

Comment: Already done that... But problem is with this part: `{provide: PrismObj, useValue: Prism}` I get: `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: are you available in team viewer?

Comment: Yes how to connect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137830/discussion-between-aravind-and-vladimir).

Comment: what is the solution for this issue then?