# Using OpaqueToken in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using OpaqueToken in my sample Angular 2 application , and below is the related code

```
//app.module.ts
......
....
export const MY_CONFIG_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('MY_CONFIG_TOKEN');

providers: [
         { provide: MY_CONFIG_TOKEN, useValue: {test:'test'} }
         ]
....
.....
```

Below is my  related root component code where I am using the token for dependency injection

```
....
....
constructor(@Inject(MY_CONFIG_TOKEN) private myconfig:any,){}
```

Running this application in browser throws below error

> Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent

Any idea what could be the reason for this error.
Please let me know if more information needs to be provided.

Comment: Try removing `,` from constructor that you wrote after `any`. Here `myconfig:any,`

Comment: still the same error

Comment: Refer this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42235540/plain-javascript-as-angular-2-service/42235817#42235817) and follow steps as such

Comment: change the `const` to `let`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/pDNFSP?p=preview showing how OpaqueToken is used.
Here is how you define an OpaqueToken:

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';
export let MY_CONFIG_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('configToken');
```

Then you import it in your main module:

```
import { MY_CONFIG_TOKEN } from './token';
```

Then you register it under providers

```
providers: [{provide: MY_CONFIG_TOKEN, useValue: {test:'test'} }],
```

and finally you can use it like this:

```
constructor(@Inject(MY_CONFIG_TOKEN) private myconfig:any) {
    myconfig.value = "Hello";
    console.log(myconfig.value);
  }
```

In the App component, I have attached a dummy "value" property to token and displayed it in console after setting it in constructor.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Modify this

```
export const MY_CONFIG_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('MY_CONFIG_TOKEN');
```

to

```
declare let MY_CONFIG_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken(window_object);
```

Comment: this shows compile time type script error , "Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts."

Comment: I am using Angular cli , don't know if that information helps

Comment: did you follow those steps as such? and still not working?